# How do I send SMS without launching Text application?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, sms

I am developing a simple application which has to send an SMS message from the app itself instead of launching the native Text app.

Here's my action now. What should I change to achieve my desired functionality?

```
-(IBAction)startButtonPressed
{
    NSString *phoneNumber = @"13136296693";
    NSString *url           = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"sms:%@",phoneNumber];
    NSLog(@"Send SMS to: %@ ", url); 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

Thanks!

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done with the current SDK. I believe Apple announced that applications in iPhone OS 4.0 will be able to do this, using a similar interface to the existing `MFMailComposeViewController` malarkey.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check into that now.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken I think sending text messages via your own application is only available in the iPhone 4.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what apple says:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140604143837/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html

Here's a tutorial fon another forum.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html

It's still not entirely automated.  The user has to tap the send button.  I haven't gotten it working yet.  Tell me if you have better luck.  If you can think of a way for me to program my app to "tap" the send button instead of the user, let me know.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller